# Does solr increases the score of a document based on no of hits?

Tags: solr

Somebody told me that solr increases the score of a document based on no of hits. Is this true? If yes, could somebody give a authentic link from lucene or solr pages? I ran a query multiple times, but i don't see the score of the resultant documents increasing. So this doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: Solr does not handle this out of the box. You would need the store the hits in a separate field and boost it.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra. That's what i need.  I don't want to increase the score of a document on no of hits. So i am fine.

Comment: you can store the count in separate store (db or no sql) and maybe use the external file feature to refer it. Check out the external field.